# How to sum an array of hashes to an array in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a simpler way to do this?

What I try to do here is simply add the `item` hashes inside each `list` to `myarray`

```
myarray = []
list = [{list: [{item: 'item1'},{item: 'item2'}]}, {list: [{item: 'item3'},{item: 'item4'}]}, {list: [{item: 'item5'},{item: 'item6'}]}]

list.each do |list| 
  myarray = myarray + list
end
```

Comment: It's not clear from your post what you want the result to be since you don't have any "item hashes".  You have an array of hashes with `list` as the key, but I don't think you mean that.  Are you saying you want a simple array made up of "item1, item2, item3, etc." ?

Comment: What's the problem with your current solution? What's your expected output?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom Yes, I do want an array with all the item hashes: item1, item2, item3, item4, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
((list.map {|x| x[:list]}).flatten).map{|x| x[:item] if x != nil}
```

produces this:

```
["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", nil]
```

(the nil is because your last element is

```
{item: [{item: 'item5'},{item: 'item6'}]}
```

I assume you meant list: just like in the others.